# A good way to pass IConfiguration to static class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, retrypolicy

I am using this [dapper extension](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hyrmn/ce124e9b1f50dbf9d241390ebc8f6df3/raw/cdb4f3ba0d3676d7d3111c1204df7219c4726572/DapperExtensions.cs) that uses polly for retry.

We can see that it defines a static retry policy:

```
private static readonly AsyncRetryPolicy RetryPolicy = 
    Policy
        .Handle<SqlException>(SqlServerTransientExceptionDetector.ShouldRetryOn)
        .Or<TimeoutException>()
        .OrInner<Win32Exception>(SqlServerTransientExceptionDetector.ShouldRetryOn)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(RetryTimes,
            (exception, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
            {
                LogTo.Warning(
                    exception,
                    "WARNING: Error talking to ReportingDb, will retry after {RetryTimeSpan}. Retry attempt {RetryCount}",
                    timeSpan,
                    retryCount
                );
            });
```

Ideally I want to make `RetryTimes` a setting. However, I am not sure how can I pass `IConfiguration` to `RetryTimes` in a static property?

The work round I can think of is to define the polly policy as a Singleton (so I can read the setting). Then in this extension method, I actually pass the policy in. Is this about the right way to hanlde it in .NET Core?

Comment: set the static policy during startup after already getting access to the configuration.

Comment: How are you using the policy in your code? If you're using `RetryPolicy` in a class that's resolved from the DI, you can also resolve the retry policy as singleton from the DI.

Answer (score 0):

I think create a place to hold the setting and assign to it before you use would be fine.

```
// Create the holder class
public static class SettingHolder
{
    public static int RetryTimes = 0;
}

// Assign to it before you going to use it, in startup file would be nice.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            SettingHolder.RetryTimes = int.Parse(Configuration.GetSection("YourSection")["GoToYourSetting"]);
        }
```